# get the progress with animate() JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-animate

Here is the spinet:

```
$('#processing .progress-bar').animate({'width':'60%'},4000);
```

Is it possible to display how the milliseconds are being countdown by the function?

for instance I want to be able to display:

```
4000
3000
2000
1000
0000
```

then the function stops

Comment: Are you wanting to show 1% 2% 3%?

Comment: yeah preferably. thanks

Comment: there is a way to do what you want, ill post an example in a sec

Comment: I will be waiting for it

Comment: Hope my answer help you

Comment: @william.eyidi ive posted an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `step` function to the jquery animate, and inside calcualte how much time is left for the animation to finish:

```js
$(function () {
    var Now = 0;
    var animationDuration = 4000;
    var DesiredWidth = "200";

    $(".test").animate({
        width: DesiredWidth
    }, {
        easing:"linear",
        duration: animationDuration,
        //the argument in the step call back function will hold the
        // current position of the animated property - width in this case.
        step: function (currentWidth,fx) {
            Now = Math.round((100/DesiredWidth)*currentWidth);
            $(".ms_span").text(Now+"%");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
<br/>Percent: <span class="ms_span">
```

Comment: thanks for the sharp answer, I will implement and validate the answer.

Comment: @you are welcomed. note however, that i miscalculated the time in the step function, all you need to do is get it right but the point is the same.

Comment: +1 Awesome answer! I can't believe I forgot about `step` and `progress`. I updated my answer to use `progress` since you used `step`.

Comment: @william.eyidi fixed to show percentage as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

After looking at @Banana's solution, I realized that I had completely forgotten about the `step` function and the new(ish) `progress` function, both of which can be passed to `.animate`. My updated solution is below, and I have removed the other to avoid confusion.

```js
var $steps = $("#steps");
$('#processing .progress-bar').animate({
  'width': '60%'
}, {
  duration: 4000,
  progress: function(prom, prog, rem) {
    $steps.html("Prog: " + prog + "<br/>Rem: " + rem);
  }
});
```

```css
#processing {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 25px;
}
#processing .progress-bar {
  height: 100%;
  background: lime;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="processing">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div> <span id="steps"></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

As a side-note, depending on what you are planning to use this for, the other thing that you might want to look into is jQuery's `.progress` method, which handles progress notifications. Note that I am fairly certain that calling `.progress` on animations themselves won't have any effect unless you use a solution like the above to make progress notifications at each step of the animation. This is done with calls to `.notify` or `.notifyWith` but doing this in an animation is a little extreme. Regardless, this can be useful for situations in which you have an asynchronous call running for an indeterminate amount of time.

- [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) for `deferred.promise`.
- [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/) for `deferred.notify`.
- [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.notifyWith/) for `deferred.notifyWith`.

Comment: that is a good approach but you call the function clearInterval in a callBack function that will only be performed at the end of the animation. I will look into progress inside the doc. I will let the question not answer for now waiting for a complete answer. thanks

Comment: The reason why `clearInterval` is called in the callback is because that interval should run at the same time as the animation. When the animation ends, it stops the interval from continuing. It's not actually notifying you of a step in the animation, but rather think of it like someone with a stop watch counting how long it takes and printing a message when you tell it to.

Comment: the function intrvl() executes pretty much at the same time as the main function itself. I will implement it and tell you how it goes. thanks for the sharp answer

Comment: No problem. I actually messed up a bit and forgot about the `step` and `progress` functions that you can pass as parameters, as well. I remembered after seeing @banana's answer. Banana used the `step` function, so I used the `progress` function in mine. It's relatively new, and actually has support for calculating both progress and time remaining built-in.

Comment: +one, i completely forgot about progress too :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var duration = 4000,
    interval = 1000,
    pbar = $('#processing .progress-bar');

pbar.text( duration );

var cd = setInterval(function() {
  duration -= interval;
  pbar.text( duration );
}, interval);

pbar.animate({'width':'60%'}, duration, function() {
  clearInterval(cd);
  pbar.text( '0000' );
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="processing">
  <div class="progress-bar">pBar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: htanks for the answer, but where is the function clearInterval declared?

Comment: It's a cousin of setInterval --- it's inbuilt.

Comment: ok thanks, I got it into the manual, I will implement and validate the answer.